# Door very stiff, how to fix?

Tags: repair, doors, hinges

My home's door has been replaced with a heavier fire door, however it's super stiff now and requires a lot of strength to open. I think the door itself is quite heavy, but I also think that the 'stiffness' it's given by the hinges.
We also have an auto-mechanism but that doesn't seem to be affecting this.

Is there a way I can regulate the hinges and make this door less difficult to open? I'm not an expert whatsover so please explain in an easy way :)

Comment: Hinges can't really create the stiffness you describe. Even if they're spring hinges they won't feel heavy. Does the door drag on the threshold? What's an "auto mechanism"?

Comment: With auto mechanism I mean that thing that you install at the top to make the door close automatically. I tried to adjust the valves of this, but the stiffness wasn't really affected in anyway...so I'm not sure

Comment: That's likely the problem. Have you read the operation manual? Post the model number of the closer.

Comment: 73 series size 3 door

Comment: The instructions are [here](http://www.frisco-group.co.uk/products/door_controls/73_series.html#horizontalTab5). If adjusting the valves doesn't help, I'm not sure what else to tell you without being able to see it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I will try again! And you definitely think it's not the hinges that are making the door more difficult to open? Could it be that it's the door itself?

Comment: try some oil or WD40 on the moving parts.

Comment: Could you post a picture of the door and one of the closer? That would help put context in your question so people can see what the models are and whether there's anything unusual going on.